# Lost data when moving page to page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form to post with for example "title" data, once the submit button is pressed, the model will be used to process the data. the controller then uses the processed data to display in a view to the user. That is the flow I follow.
After getting the view, the user will choose to edit something. he thus needs to get back to the edittable form (same as the original one) to fix the title data.  Here is the form

```
<?php form_open("blog/edit_updated")?>
          Title:<input type="text" col="30" value="<?=$edit[0]['title']?>" name="edit_title"/><br/>
          Comment:<br/><textarea name="edit_comment" width="20" col="5"><?=$edit[0]['comment']?></textarea><br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="postcomment" value="TRUE"/>          
          <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
         <?=form_close()?>
```

That form will call the following controler function

```
public function edit_updated()
    {        
        if(!file_exists('application/views/blog/edit_succeed.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($this->url_title);

            if($this->blog->update_row_with_title(XXXXX,$_POST['edit_title'],$_POST['edit_comment']))
               $this->load->view('blog/edit_succeed');
        }

    }
```

the function update_row_with_title is only used to seach and update the specified item with exact match of the given title. I test and it always return one (UPDATE command is used). XXXX is the title of the NOT_YET_TO_FIX title used to search in the database, the rest of parameters are those newly entered fields that will be used for SET in UPDATE command. However, XXXXX is always empty. Could you tell me a way to retrieve the original title  ?

Summary

Form 1 (with data)--> post --> use data as part of url for GET --> fix the form (with new data) --> UPDATE [right here I lost the original data that is used as an identity for db searching]

Comment: XXXXX is a php variable like $table_name or something?

Comment: Don't use title to find the row you want to update, but id.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ambiguous your description, I'm not sure I understand what you want, but I'll try to offer a solution.

If you need the old title in the controller method you can actually send that as a parameter to it in the URL. To do this you have to make the following changes:

1. in the view containing the form change the argument of form_open to something like

> ```
> <?php form_open("blog/edit_updated/" . $edit[0]['title'])?>
> ```

1. add an argument to the edit_updated() controller method like this

> ```
> public function edit_updated($old_title = null) {
>     ...
>     ...
> }
> ```

and now in the controller method you can replace that `XXXXXX` variable with `$old_title`.

Was this helpful ?